# ssh connection freeze when try to connect to ngrok

Tags: linux, ssh, openssh

i'm trying to connect to my Linux server with ngrok but when i try to connect to ngrok URL it freeze can anyone tell me how can i solve this problem
my ssh log :

```
ssh -vvv kosh@0.tcp.ngrok.io -p18650
OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "0.tcp.ngrok.io" port 18650
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 0.tcp.ngrok.io [3.19.3.150] port 18650.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/white0wl/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/white0wl/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/white0wl/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/white0wl/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/white0wl/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/white0wl/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/white0wl/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/white0wl/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3
```

after i ssh session status in ngrok shows opn 1 and then nothing happen.

Answer (score 0):

When an SSH client connects to an SSH server, the first data passed through the connection is a version string sent from the server to the client. The `ssh` debug messages look like this:

```
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.9
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.9
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.9 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
```

According to your debug trace, your ssh client is connecting to something and waiting for the version string. But whatever you've connected to doesn't send a version string.

The simplest explanation is that you're not connecting to an SSH server. You might be connecting to an HTTP server or something else.

Alternately, if you are connecting to an SSH server, it's malfunctioning somehow.

Comment: many thanks for your response kenster i try this with another system but i get the same problem with it so with your suggestion i think some thing wrong with my config i did these steps for my connection: 1) check ssh service config 2)connect to ssh service locally 3)when i did step 2 successfully i setup ngrok with " ./ngrok tcp 22 " command 4)try to connect ngrok URL locally and remotly with no success --did i do wrong in these steps?